# Freezing bootstrap according while creating from AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance, bootstrap-4

Actually in my website i populate bootstrap according dynamically when an according is opened, once it has been open the data is saved.

The issue is that when i open the according for first time it's freezing (as it have to append a lot of divs) and that trigger me a lot, so i would know how should i make it more performable or like which approach should i take to prevent that freezing.

[image]

The AJAX method is build as the following:

```
function getBody(body, key) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "casse.aspx/getBody",
        data: JSON.stringify({ key: key }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {

            data = r.d;
            data = $.parseJSON(data);

            $.each(data, function (i, item) {

                var piva = item.piva;
                var desmag = item.desmag;
                var via = item.via;
                var loc = item.loc;
                var servb2b = item.servb2b;
                var idtrabb2b = item.idtrabb2b;
                var matricola = item.matricola;
                var azzer = item.azzer;
                var mac = item.mac;
                var vp = item.vp;
                var vb = item.vb;
                var dr = item.dr;
                var vu = item.vu;
                var cpu = item.cpu;
                var rt = item.giart;
                var datart = item.avviort;

                var card = "";

                card += '<div class="row ml-2 mr-2">';
                card += '<div class="col">';
                card += '<div class="row"><span class="badge badge-primary">Cliente</span></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">P.Iva</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + piva + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Info Negozio</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + desmag + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Via</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + via + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Localita</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + loc + '</p></div></div>';

                card += '<div class="col">';
                card += '<div class="row"><span class="badge badge-primary">Software</span></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">VisualPos</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><a href="#" class="badge badge-warning">' + vp + '</a></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">VisualB2B</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><a href="#" class="badge badge-warning">' + vb + '</a></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Driver</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><a href="#" class="badge badge-warning">' + dr + '</a></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">VisualUpdate</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + vu + '</p></div></div>';

                card += '<div class="col">';
                card += '<div class="row"><span class="badge badge-primary">Fiscale</span></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Matricola</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + matricola + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Azzeramento Fiscale</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + azzer + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">RT</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + rt + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Data Avvio RT</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + datart + '</p></div></div>';

                card += '<div class="col">';
                card += '<div class="row"><span class="badge badge-primary">Fatturazione Elettronica</span></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Servizio B2B</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + servb2b + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">Trasmittente B2B</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + idtrabb2b + '</p></div></div>';

                card += '<div class="col">';
                card += '<div class="row"><span class="badge badge-primary">Hardware</span></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">CPU</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + cpu + '</p></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><small class="text-muted">MAC</small></div>';
                card += '<div class="row"><p class="info">' + mac + '</p></div></div></div>';

                $(body).find('.card-body').append(card);
            });

        },
        error: function (error) {
            OnFailure(error);
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

And called when the according is triggered

```
$('.accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
    var item = '#' + $(e.target).attr('id');
    if ($(item).find('.card-body').is(':empty')) {
        getBody(item, id);
    } else {

    }

});
```

Comment: Try appending to the DOM one time instead of multiple times in your loop.  Append one single time after your html string is built through the loop.

Comment: @DanD actually that had no effect

Comment: What happens if you use `shown.bs.collapse` instead?  That's "show***n***", with an "n" at the end.

Comment: I'm almost certain the issue is that you are blowing away the start and end states of the CSS transition by adjusting the content size of the collapse element during the transition.  I'm just not sure how you can tell the collapse to wait until you're done with the AJAX call before running the animation.

Comment: @zero298 by using shown it's working a bit better as the animation is "stuck" for a little but then it's blowing up all the content https://gyazo.com/d5618b0af5966de6871a010a15a57a64

Comment: @zero298 i was supposed too to open the accordion after the AJAX finish it's operations but actually didn't find anything on how i can achieve it, now i'd try to search better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to manually trigger the toggle after the data has finished loading, and after you have put your data into the DOM.  That means you need to remove the `data-target` value from your Collapse and manually add the event listener/handler.  I wish that there was a pre/post collapse aspect that you could hook to, but there isn't.

Consider the example below that doesn't have the lag you experience.

```js
$("#test-button").click(e => {
  $.ajax({
     url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",
     dataType: "json"
  }).done(d => {
    $("#collapseOne .card-body").text(JSON.stringify(d
, null, 4));
    $("#collapseOne").collapse("toggle");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button id="test-button" class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was it, now on accordion click instead of triggering collapse i'm just getting the accordion id which i'm collapsing on the AJAX done, thank you.